# RabbitMQ ignore config "heartbeat" rule

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, amqp

RabbitMQ 3.10.1

```
rabbitmq-diagnostics status

...
Config files

* /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
...
```

rabbitmq.config:

```
[
  {rabbit,
    [
      {heartbeat, 90}
    ]
  }
].
```

RabbitMQ Management show 5s heartbeat
[image]

And log:

```
2022-05-13 19:56:43.235925+03:00 [error] <0.5979.0> closing AMQP connection <0.5979.0> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3555 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5672): 
2022-05-13 19:56:43.235925+03:00 [error] <0.5979.0> missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 5s
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the heartbeat to 90s in the client. Most clients are able to set the heartbeat (from the client). RabbitMQ will respect the heartbeat suggested by the client. More about that here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#heartbeats-timeout